# Making changes that stay after moving around the page JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have a question about Jquery and I cant find the answer.
I have to work with an already setup page, and the only thing that I can use is JS.
So, I want to change for example a text or append some div in the page.
I can do it, but after moving around the page, the change that i made is gone.
How this works in Jquery?

Example

```
$('#account a[href="customer-orders.html"] span').html('<svg class="svg-icon svg-icon-heavy mr-2"><use xlink:href="#paper-bag-1"></use></svg> My Orders')
```

The html change but just once, if i go to the next page and the came back is gone.

Comment: It's gone because you "reload" the page, so the changes is back to normal

Comment: yes, i undertand that part, but i even put the change in a function and keep dissapearing after moving around. Any way to keep de changes?

Comment: only way to do is use the html local storage to store a flag variable and each time the page loads, check for the local storage and set the required content, if the flag variable is set.

Comment: You can't. You have to reapply the changes on each load or store them somewhere besides JavaScript memory, which is volatile.